# Jquery .removeattr() working issue when DOM is loaded with AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a DOM structure somewhat like this:

```
<div id="main_common_listing_form">
    <form id="frmlist" method='POST'>
....
        <select id="refine_search">
            <option value="noValueSelected" selected="selected">Please select search key</option>
            ....
        </select>
....
    </form>
</div>
```

I am replacing the form element with another form element with the same structure through ajax. After that replacement, I am trying to remove the selected attribute from the option element that has the selected attribute. 
The javascript that I've written is:

```
$("#main_common_listing_form").on("change", function(){
    $(this).find("#refine_search option[selected='selected']").removeAttr("selected");
})
```

this is working fine before the replacement of the form element, but this is not doing the required, after the form element is replaced. Can anyone help me in resolving this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a separate function and call it in your AJAX success?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
    $(document).on("change","#main_common_listing_form", function(){
        $(this).find("#refine_search option[selected='selected']").removeAttr("selected");
    })
```

**Reason** : you applied event on the element which is replaced by new one. so new element doesn't have event attach to it.

so use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to attach event. so your newly created element will have that event attach to it

jQuery delegate description

> Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.